# hook_init() is not working in my custom module

Tags: hooks

In my custom Drupal 7 module I am using `CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME_init()` function. But it is not triggered while page execution. Any suggestions?

Comment: you'll get better answers if we can see your code. try gist.github.com or drupalbin.com

Comment: I'm not sure if this will apply to you, I am running Drupal 6, but my problems with this were fixed when I adjusted the module weight in the system table in the DB.

Answer (score 6):

Hook implementations are cached in Drupal 7. After implementing a new hook, you need to clear the cache. See [What method is used to clear caches in the Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100/what-method-is-used-to-clear-caches-in-the-drupal) for ways to do that.

Comment: Yes. I cleared the cache. But not invoked

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that the module is enabled (don't laugh, I forget that sometimes).
2. Make sure that the page is not served from cache. Use [hook_boot](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) if you need to perform setup tasks for cached pages.
3. Use a debugger to step through the execution. [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) is invoked at the end of  [_drupal_bootstrap_full](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_full/7).

Comment: How to debug the execution?

Comment: Caveman debugging: put `print_r` statements at relevant places of the code to get feedback about which parts of the code are executed and what values the variables hold. Because this is tedious if done often, a better solution is to install a debugging extension on the server, e.g.  [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and using an IDE that can controll the debugger, e.g. [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the documentation for [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), the hook is not invoked on cached pages. This means that, if the content of a page is found in cache, the hook implemented by your module is not invoked.

> This hook is run at the beginning of the page request. It is typically used to set up global parameters which are needed later in the request. when this hook is called, all modules are already loaded in memory.
>
> **This hook is not run on cached pages.**
>
> To add CSS or JS that should be present on all pages, modules should not implement this hook, but declare these files in their .info file.