# Moving a contrib module from /modules into the sites/all/modules folder

Tags: 7

I need to run a simple fix in my Drupal 7 website. The website administrator, not being a Drupal specialist, installed the SMTP module in the root /modules folder, instead of the /sites/all/modules folder. Now I need to upgrade the SMTP module and noticed the mistake. My first impulse was to move the SMTP folder from /modules into /sites/all/modules, and then proceed with the regular upgrade.

My question is: do you think that moving the SMTP folder from root /modules into /sites/all/modules could cause any problems, like data loss or website crash?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17657/how-to-move-installed-modules-from-sites-all-modules-to-sites-all-contrib-mo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s OK (in most cases). Drupal 7 will find new destination of module after [registry rebuilding](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/registry_rebuild/7). So, just move folders in proper destination and clear all cache.

It works for moving modules, but not for disabling and uninstalling. Don't remove module folder before complete uninstalling.

**Update:** I can move module folder even without disabling that module, because I use Drush for immediate cache clearing. In other situations it will be useful to disable module before moving.

Comment: I think the main reason to worry is the fact that Drupal stores module files’ paths in `system` table. But there is [`system_update_files_database()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_update_files_database/7) function which resolves paths while cache flushing.

Comment: Ok, it worked for me, but after some issues. First time I tried moving, the site broke with the white screen of death and a message I unfortunately did not keep. I put the folder back up on the original spot. The site resumed working. After some 2 or 3 unsuccessful attempts where I did things in a slightly different manner, I cleared cache prior to removing the SMTP folder from the root /modules folder. Right after removing, I cleared cache again and voilà, it worked.

Comment: You should flush cache immediately after moving folder, but you tried to load site normally to find link for cache clearing :) I updated my answer.