# SQL replace() function in PDO

Tags: database

I'd like to convert the instructions from [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/54355/3167) into a general script that can be reused across projects.

I'm wondering how these commands can be written in Drupal 7 PDO format:

```
UPDATE `system` SET filename = replace(filename, 'sites/all/modules/contrib', 'profiles/distroname/modules/contrib');
```

Is the [mysql replace function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) something generic to all SQL, or is it mysql specific? I understand this is an expression, but I'm not clear on how to use the [PDO expression](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/UpdateQuery%3A%3Aexpression/7) syntax in this case.

What are the advantages of writing it PDO, as opposed to just a simple `db_query()` with the sql query from above?  In PDO, will this truly be db agnostic?

Answer (score 2):

Would it be something like this?

```
db_update('system')->
  expression('filename', 'replace(filename, :old, :new)', array(
    ':old' => 'sites/all/modules/contrib',
    ':new' => 'profiles/distroname/modules/contrib'
  ))
  ->execute();
```