# How to clear cache externally?

Tags: 7, views, caching

I'd like some help how to clear the cache using an external script. I have a script that adds nodes each night, and I'd also like it to clear the views cache so - without having to make out by myself the MySQL query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to clear one or two particular cache bins you can use [`cache_clear_all()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7) (assuming your script has Drupal bootstrapped):

```
cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_views');
cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_views_data');
```

Comment: Since it is a non-Drupal script, I'll probably do it like that, and include() the necessary files. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you are running a script, you'll likely benefit from using [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).  With the Drush php-eval and php-script commands, you can easily call a snippet of php code (such as the examples shown in other answers to this question) after bootstrapping Drupal.  Without Drush, you would have to set up a web service and use wget or curl to run your code, or try to call the Drupal bootstrap code yourself.  Better yet, Drush even comes with a built-in command to clear the cache, so you don't need to worry about writing any php code at all, if that's all you want to do from your script.  Just use:

```
cd /path/to/drupal/sites/default && drush cache-clear all
```

You may also wish to learn about site aliases; if you define an alias called @site, then you can instead use:

```
drush @site cache-clear all
```

Comment: Drush seems like the clear solution here, though OP wants to clear Views cache.  Try `drush cc views` in your script as a user with the correct access.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about `drush cc views`; however, Drush commands by convention usually call API functions directly, without access checks; it is not usually necessary to specify a user.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have that kind of access on this server. Otherwise I really much enjoy Drush!

Answer (score 6):

I suggest register menu and externally call it ,in call back of it put your code(clear cache )

```
function yourmodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['customclearcache'] = array(
        'title' => 'clear cache',
        'description' => 'clear cache',
        'page callback' => 'yourmodule_clear_cache',
        'access callback' => TRUE , // or any access you need
    );
    return $items;
}


 function yourmodule_clear_cache(){
   cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_views');
   cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_views_data');
   drupal_set_message(t('cache clearing completed'));
   drupal_goto("node"); // or any page you want
}
```

and you can clear cache with calling this url : `yoursite.com/customclearcache`.

Also if you installed `drush` clear cache with it `drush cc all`

```
   //first go to your installed site path
  $cd /path/to/drupal 
   $drush cc all
```

Comment: Make sure to check access, repeatedly calling that url could otherwise easily bring your site down

Comment: @Berdir , yes, I am agree with you, this just a way can get idea and develop it.

Comment: The script is outside of actual Drupal code. This would be perfect for my module, but not in this precise case. But thanks!

Comment: A callback like this should check some secret token and ideally an anti-csrf token to avoid abuse.

Comment: @greggles yes I agree with you , or specified access callback ;)

Comment: Access callback is good if you can, but in a job it's probably not great. A CSRF token is also important to avoid being tricked into visiting the url.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to clear the cache externally is by using Drush commands.

You could use `drush cc` in the terminal and it will ask you what exactly you want to clear. In example it will ask for:

Enter a number to choose which cache to clear.

```
 [0]   :  Cancel         
 [1]   :  all            
 [2]   :  drush          
 [3]   :  theme-registry 
 [4]   :  menu           
 [5]   :  css-js         
 [6]   :  block          
 [7]   :  module-list    
 [8]   :  theme-list     
 [9]   :  registry       
 [10]  :  views
```

Select you option and you could clear the cache externally.

For more details about the drush and commands of it you could visit [drush GitHub page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the cache externally, the easiest way is to use `drush`, for example:

```
drush -y cc all
```

which would clear all Drupal caches (but not [all caches](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/124707/1908)). In Drupal 8: `drush cr`.

Other way is to write a simple script which would truncate/delete all tables which starts with `cache_`, for example using the following one-liner:

```
echo "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cache%'" | drush sqlc --extra=--skip-column-names | xargs -L1 -I% echo "DELETE FROM %;" | drush sqlc --extra=-v
```

Answer (score -2):

`TRUNCATE` the `cache_views` table in the database.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: Its alright. But yeah, I didn't want to it like that, but rather using a "safe" Drupal function.